# How to extract an xpath sibling elements that are some number of elements (n) away from another sibling element?

Tags: xml, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have been parsing the HTML of the github documentation page and learning a bit about xpath in the process.

I was wondering if anyone here knew of a way to extract any sibling element that is n units away from an original element. In my example I am trying to extract elements that are within 10 units of an element that I parse.

I grab my elements from the [github api documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/)

Then using selenium with python I get returned a list of elements from the xpath statement:

```
'//pre/code'
```

From here I do some analysis on the text contained within the above xpath, and finally I want to return elements that are within 10 units of the above xpath elements.

Would really appreciate any help you have to offer.

Comment: by 'n units' I meant within a certain number (n) of sibling elements. Will correct now, I suppose the link could be removed. Also not really sure that the link would reduce quality of answer even if it did go down...

Comment: I appreciate that link @JeffC 
Read it, and will be formatting questions accordingly going forward! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this XML,

```
<r>
  <pre id="i1"><code/></pre>
  <pre id="i2"><code/></pre>
  <pre id="i3"><code/></pre>
  <pre id="i4"><code/></pre>
  <pre id="i5"><code/></pre>
  <pre id="i6"><code/></pre>
  <pre id="i7"><code/></pre>
  <pre id="i8"><code/></pre>
  <pre id="i9"><code/></pre>
</r>
```

this XPath 1.0 expression,

```
//pre[   @id="i5"
      or following-sibling::pre[3 >= position()][@id="i5"]
      or preceding-sibling::pre[3 >= position()][@id="i5"]]
```

will select the `i5` `pre` element along with 3 preceding and 3 following sibling `pre` elements,

```
<pre id="i2"><code/></pre>
<pre id="i3"><code/></pre>
<pre id="i4"><code/></pre>
<pre id="i5"><code/></pre>
<pre id="i6"><code/></pre>
<pre id="i7"><code/></pre>
<pre id="i8"><code/></pre>
```

as requested.